# How to overload an operator in build-in class?

Tags: .net, operator-overloading

Somebody mentioned that it would make sense to overload + in e.g. Color struct. But how can I do it? I thought it needs to be inside of the type.

Comment: Just wondering, what happens when you `+` red and red? Double red?

Comment: @gaearon: I would assume it would be something along the lines of `Color.FromARGB(Math.Min(255, c1.A + c2.A), ...)`

Answer (score 5):

That's correct; there's no way to add operator overloading to an *existing* type (there are no extension operators).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't pursue this - it would probably be cleaner to create an extension method Add(Color c1, Color c2)

Answer (score 0):

Operators involve 2 operands, and you have the chance of placing the operator overload into eather of the 2 types involved.

In other words, you can write your own custom type, and add operators that makes it interact with Color, but if you want Color and int to interact with new operators, then sorry, no, you can´t do that.